# Select List onChange not working if the option value is "True"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC.net to generate a form with a select list. When the user changes the select list i want the form to automatically submit.  I have the following code:

```
<select OnChange="$(&#39;#FormID&#39;).submit();" id="LinkedToInvoice" name="LinkedToInvoice">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="True">Yes</option>
    <option selected value="False">No</option>
</select>
```

Which should work and in fact it does some of the time.  If i change the dropdown to "Select" it submits the form, if i change to "No" it submits the form.  However when i change the dropdown to "Yes" (value = true) the form does not submit.  If i change the value from True to anything else it fires correctly but the value="True" seems to stop the onchange event. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Is the `No` value selected by default, as your code implies, or is it the `Yes` value? Choosing the value that is currently selected does not count as a change.

Comment: When the page loads No is selected. If i select "Yes" the onchange does not fire. if i select the "Select" option the on change fires. Basically if i change the value from anything else to yes the on change is not firing.

Comment: Do you have a `submit` event handler bound to the form somewhere that could reject the submission if `Yes` is selected (maybe while validating the form's data)?

Comment: I'm using a jquery ajaxs form plug in to submit forms via ajax (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) and i've just done some testing and changed the form submit to an alert instead and it is working as expected however for some reason the form is not submitting.  Which i assume is a fault somewhere in the Jquery plug in.  I will investigate further and update my question with any results. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As you work away a side question for you: is the id of your form actually 'FormID'?

Comment: No its CaseFinance_PayChequeDetailsForm i just changed it in the example, the code is correct just not consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my mistake the onchange event was correctly fireing but the form submit was failing. I am using jquery ajax forms to submit the forms and i didnt include any fault checking.  When the true value was passed to the server my code caused a error 500 on the server however no message was shown on the web page. Adding fault checking to my ajax form call solved the issue and allowed me to locate the cause of the error 500.